# Nginx with wordpress 404 on all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Although this issue has been answered many times but still its not working for me.
I am getting 404 on all pages except home page on Nginx.

I am posting in my configuration below:

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/p/swear;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name skinnybikiniswimwear.org;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /$uri/ /index.php?args =404;
        }


            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                try_files $uri /index.php?args =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

I am not able to find the issue in this configuration.

Wordpress is installed at: /var/www/html/p/swear

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
    location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args =404;
    }


    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }
```

Having had a lot of failures configuring wordpress to work with nginx, the rewrite rule solves every issue with the 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

try removing slash in front of `/$uri/`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

Comment: Did you restart nginx before you said that this doesn't work?

Comment: Looks to me that all of your other urls except for the homepage point to https urls, and that could be why you are getting a connection refused error. That's what I am getting atleast.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich, I think it should be `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;`, without `&` (it will caused 500 error). You are right about the https, which I think ewwink should also check the setting under Settings -> General -> Wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) under the  Admin panel.

Comment: Yes they point to https, but I tried http, Earlier site was working on https with apache.

Comment: Can't really help as, honestly there can be a lot going on with the server config, including permission issues. Quick tip, "sudo nginx -t" will check your config file for syntax errors. Also, if it helps, here is a server block setup I know that is working on one of my servers for https if it helps. https://gist.github.com/DZuz14/860d0a6c6752c6048780305d340b37a2

Comment: Also, my sites are on Wordpress too, and I never put in any 404 directives, as Wordpress should handle it for you if you have a 404 template in your theme.

Comment: Answer by above user worked, now images are not rendering only.

Comment: it is because image still use `https`

Comment: Yeah, I found out that. Trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Images does not because you dont have nothing in your server block about images. You have to add the images into your server block.

For example:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mp3)$ {
        root /home/example/public_html
    }
```

Comment: Ok I will check this. Thanks

Comment: Please accept and update your code with the parts which worked. @viv

Comment: @viv could you update your server configuration then in your initial post ?